# How to remove specific JSON property from JSON string

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm setting up audit log for web api. Here i would like to remove password property from json string because of security reason. I don't want to log login password for login API.

Json/Request Payload:

```
{"code":"medics1","username":"admin","password":"password"}
```

I tried with below code:

```
var payload = JArray.Parse(objQueue.payload);
payload.Remove("password");
```

Comment: Can you provide us what you have tried so far...? Any code or implementation

Comment: Please check updated question

Comment: @NayanRudani, I adde my answer below with output screenshot. Try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closed to your goal. You need just one little change in your code.

You are using `JArray` and this is use for parsing json that start and end with `[...]` not for `{...}`

And your json is a `JObject` that means its start and end with `{...}`

So just use `JObject` instead of `JArray` and then it will works

```
string json = @"{ 'code':'medics1','username':'admin','password':'password'}";

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

jObject.Remove("password");

string outputJson = jObject.ToString();
```

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use jobject parse here.   Below code from newtonsoft site should be helpful

```
string json = @"{
    'channel': {
     'title': 'Star Wars',
     'link': 'http://www.starwars.com',
     'description': 'Star Wars blog.',
     'obsolete': 'Obsolete value',
     'item': []
    }
 }";

JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);
JObject channel = (JObject)rss["channel"];
channel.Property("obsolete").Remove();
```

You do not have named object, hence you can directly call

```
rss.Property(“password”).Remove();
```

Another alternative aproach is to deserialize into a class which ignores password property and then serialize it again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost correct, just you have to deserialize into an object instead of an array based on your JSON string.

```
string str = @"{'code':'medics1','username':'admin','password':'password'}";
JObject j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(str);
j.Remove("password");
Console.WriteLine(j.ToString(Formatting.Indented));
```

Outputting:

```
{
  "code": "medics1",
  "username": "admin"
}
```